# boolean and mirror problem

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I am learning Anvil tutorial by Blender Guru ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM&lc=UgxYwargR0WppMjn-7d4AaABAg)) and whenever I try to mirror the anvil after using boolean I am able to do it but for some reason, I am having the base of the anvil as it is and there is no face where boolean is used. [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CVkh9-R657ovUu6sKtd19RlMd59-QdNu/view) is the blend file.

P.S this object is in a collection named "2nd try" and my blender version is 2.92
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just move your mirror modifier before your boolean modifier like this:

[image]

Then it works:

[image]

UPDATE:

ok, then just add a mirror modifier for your cut object (cylinder) too like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

blend file:

[image]

Comment: it's solving my one problem but creating another i.e it's not mirroring it to the other side where I want the same cut

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: it's the same there is no difference in your answer.

Comment: quick ques. if I use mirror first then boolean then won't the anvil will be mirrored then boolean is applied but what I want to do if use boolean to add cut to anvil then mirror the cut part to the opposite side of the anvil as well

Comment: sorry, forgot to save. now.

Comment: can you share the blend file?

Comment: sure. done.......